# Gnome Tweak Tool does not show extensions

Tags: extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I cannot use the user the gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme because there is no button on the tweak tool to enable extensions!
I've completely uninstalled and reinstalled the gnome-tweak-tool, no difference. Any suggestions?
Bruce.

Comment: Having the same issue, didn't notice this post before, here is mine: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74119/enabled-shell-extensions-for-custom-themes-in-11-10 let me know if you figure out the problem

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Seems that the file **metadata.json** has a wrong shell-version. At least for Ubuntu 11.10. To solve the issue I had to:

- cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
- cd into the desired extension directory.
- edit the metadata.json file and change

```
 
"shell-version": [ "3.3.2" ] 
to 
"shell-version": [ "3.2" ],
```

- logout from Gnome-Shell and login again. Now you should see all the estensions in gnome-tweak-tool.

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird answer.. after a clean installation of Ubuntu 13.04 i realized that neither the gnome.extensions.org works (all the extensions are greyed out) nor the Gnome Tweak tool worked..

I tried following many steps (and reverting them). The simplest was to go back to the Login page and change the desktop manager from the default Ubuntu to Gnome.. That fixed all the issues.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

@Tymoteusz Stępień 's Answer worked for me. I had been trying to solve this issue for the last 2 months, googled a lot, read a lot of post but none worked. However this answer worked like a charm.

*Note:* Make sure that, the directory name of extension you are manually trying to install is the same as the value of uuid in the metadata.json file of that extension.

I installed the extension GSConnect . In my case the value of `uuid` was: `"gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io"` inside of `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gsconnectandyholmes.github.io.v43.shell-extension/metadata.json`.

You can check uuid of your extension using

```
egrep "uuid" ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/{YourExtensionNameHere}/metadata.json
```

The output for me was `"uuid": "gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io",`.

Copy the value of uuid without the double quotation marks, here gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io and rename the directory of that extension to the value of its uuid.

In my case I renamed the directory

```
gsconnectandyholmes.github.io.v43.shell-extension
```

to

```
gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
```

inside of

```
 ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

I had now same problem but on my Debian 9 fresh installation.

Check if your `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/{extension directory}/metadata.json` have 664 permissions. I had 400

After `chmod 664 ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/{extension directory}/metadata.json` it shown correctly in gnome-tweak-tool

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem 10 minutes ago :D. This very brief command saved the day:

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
```

It purges all installations and references for the proprietary graphics driver and once you restart gnome-shell, 3D acceleration is re-enabled and gnome-shell plus other applications requiring 3D acceleration run properly.