# Cannot enable Shell Extensions for custom themes

Tags: 11.10, gnome, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

I've followed the steps posted [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/how-to-install-gnome-shell-themes-in-ubuntu-11-10/) with intentions of installing a custom theme downloaded from the previous site.

When I get to the step:

> You’ll now need to log out and back in for the extension to be ‘picked
>   up’ by the system, then enable the extension from the ‘Shell
>   Extensions’ tab in the ‘Advanced Settings/GNOME Tweak Tool’ app.

I open GNOME Tweak Tool and navigate to the Shell Extensions tab but get the following:[image: Shell Extensions screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? I cannot see the necessary options to enable shell-extension themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you logged in to GNOME Shell? Also, have you installed any extension?

As far as I know, the extensions only show up when you're logged into GNOME Shell. In Unity for instance, the Extensions tab is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting over, remove all the stuff you installed. Now, do this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme gnome-tweak-tool
```

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem (the shell extension tab was blank after installing a lot of gnome shell extensions, gnome session fallback, gnome classic session and gnome tweak tool).

After that, I had three gnome-session types to choose: Gnome, Gnome classic and Gnome classic (no effects).

The problem in my case was the session type I had left chosen. I was logging on Ubuntu in a "Gnome classic" session instead of logging in a "Gnome" session.

I think that is what Alin Andrei meant with his answer.

Logging with the "Gnome" session makes my desktop looks like the image of the link below.

[Gnome Shell Desktop](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html)

I hope that helps you.

Elias