# Gnome Shell Extension Empty

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

Here is the situation. Changed unity shell to gnome shell. Installed the gnome tweak tool, installed the shell extension, themes, etc...everything i normally need to do that is installed

When i go to gnome tweak tool, and click on shell extension, the right list is empty

I've surfed the web and questions for answer. Yes, i did restart my pc after installing everything, even restarted a couple of time.

Yes, i clicked the cog and chose GNOME instead of Ubuntu.

To no avail, i can't seem to see what is supposed to be on that right menu. I saw some screenshot, and i know it is supposed to be filled with radio buttons and such

I've tried the suggested answer here - [Gnome Tweak Tool does not show extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71181/gnome-tweak-tool-does-not-show-extensions) but this is the result:

```
   cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
   cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/: No such file or directory
```

I installed the following gnome-shell extensions which are not appearing in gnome-tweak-tool:

```
gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
gnome-shell-extensions-common
gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```

All of that info gotten from Synaptic, which i also installed!
All package were installed in root mode, updates and upgrades done

Also, the terminal just popped an error as i tryied to get into the tweak tool, first time it pop me the error:

```
CRITICAL: Error parsing schema org.gnome.shell (/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.gschema.xml)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gsettings.py", line 45, in __init__
    summary = key.getElementsByTagName("summary")[0].childNodes[0].data
IndexError: list index out of range
WARNING : Shell not running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_shell.py", line 57, in __init__
    self._shell = GnomeShellFactory().get_shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/utils.py", line 38, in getinstance
    instances[cls] = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", line 123, in __init__
    v = map(int,proxy.version.split("."))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", line 46, in version
    return json.loads(self.execute_js('const Config = imports.misc.config; Config.PACKAGE_VERSION'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", line 39, in execute_js
    result, output = self.proxy.Eval('(s)', js)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py", line 148, in __call__
    kwargs.get('flags', 0), kwargs.get('timeout', -1), None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files
WARNING : Could not list shell extensions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_shell.py", line 62, in __init__
    extensions = self._shell.list_extensions()
AttributeError: ShellThemeTweak instance has no attribute '_shell'
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_shell_extensions.py", line 145, in __init__
    shell = GnomeShellFactory().get_shell()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/utils.py", line 38, in getinstance
    instances[cls] = cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", line 123, in __init__
    v = map(int,proxy.version.split("."))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", line 46, in version
    return json.loads(self.execute_js('const Config = imports.misc.config; Config.PACKAGE_VERSION'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", line 39, in execute_js
    result, output = self.proxy.Eval('(s)', js)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py", line 148, in __call__
    kwargs.get('flags', 0), kwargs.get('timeout', -1), None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
GError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files

(gnome-tweak-tool:2327): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion `width >= 0' failed
```

I also tryied "sudo apt-get remove gnome-tweak-tool" and "sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool" to no avail. Still the same long error message

Help?

**EDIT:
I have scrapped the whole virtual machine, and reinstalled it.**

30 GB of hard drive

Ubuntu 11.10

728 MB of video memory

Home folder not encrypted

**Here is what i have done:**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Reboot

Boot into GNOME

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

*And still the same!*

Screenshot of desktop. Also, a printscreen of GNOME Tweak Tool:
[image: Screenshot of the desktop]

[image: Gnome tweak tool]

Comment: Also, foss, who keep editing all my post since earlier, thank you. I'm new to this website, and i'm kind of lacking anything on how to make my post better, i don't know how to do the quote you just did and all you did on my post. Thanks a lot for you helping me in resolving that dang issue :D

Comment: can you post a link to a screenshot of your whole desktop - I can reproduce your gnome-tweak-tool issue if I log into Gnome-Classic ... i.e. are you absolutely sure that you are seeing the full gnome-shell and not just the fallback version?

Comment: I'm 100% sure i SAW the full gnome desktop. Having no answer today, i decided to scrap out the VM machine and start a new one. I'll list the package i install if i can reproduce the bug ^^

Comment: ... go-on humour me :) lets have a look at a screenshot of your virtualbox desktop.  Thanks!

Comment: Look at the steps, i've recreated the problem from bare!!!! I'm taking a screenshot, posting it in the problem ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you are reporting with gnome-tweak-tool occurs when either logging into Gnome-Classic or if logging into Gnome-Shell - but it doesnt allow a full Gnome-Shell GUI but reverts to Gnome-fallback.

From your latest edit - this is the case - the screenshot shows that you are using gnome-fallback.  This occurs when 3D acceleration fails.

N.B. Gnome-Shell should look like:

[image]

To get the full Gnome-Shell GUI, check that your virtualbox settings have 3D acceleration checked, 128MB VGA RAM and that your host graphics supports 3D Hardware acceleration.

Comment: Oh god i feel so stupid. I mistook Memory for video memory. My machine (because i'm at work, bleh) only have 128 mb of video memory and i can't allow it all on the virtual machine. That sucks, but you surely gave the answer to that problem! Thank you for your help in that case, foss. You were a great help all along