# Gnome session doesn't look right... and shell extensions is empty?

Tags: gnome, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnome Shell Extension Empty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91118/gnome-shell-extension-empty)

I wanted to change the theme of my desktop, so I downloaded a few themes that I wanted to try and followed this [tutorial](http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/10/how-to-install-and-manage-gnome-shell.html). After following the tutorial, shell extensions is still empty and the themes that I placed inside the .themes folder does not show up on the list. More over, when logging into the Gnome session, this is what I see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVsVB.png

I don't think it's supposed to look like that. 
The panels at the top looks crappy.
What do I do? :( 
I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, on a lenovo laptop with
Intel core i5 and Nvidia Geforce (w/ cuda).

Comment: Did you try reloading the UI? (ALT+F2, type "r" (without the quotes) and click enter)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using Gnome Shell. Your desktop is Gnome Classic. So, extensions and themes are invisible because the only desktop environment that looks for Shell extensions and Shell themes is Gnome Shell, not Gnome Classic.

Maybe you have a problem with your graphic card software.